# How does $uid node works on firebase-realtime-database rules?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm working on firebase-realtime-database on ionic, I am a bit confuse about how to "read" and "write" inside the $uid node. Which i am currently dealing with denied access.

the node looks like this

```
rules {
"info": {     
   "$uid": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
   }     
 }
}
```

while my json database looks like this

```
{
  info: {
     01: {
     name:jay
     age:16
     }
  }
}
```

I am a bit confuse what steps to take in order to access the data inside the $uid node. I did try to update my json database node to this.

```
{
  info: {
    f3de4734-8fb2-42bd-971d-8e693f8aab3b: {  // auth.uid of dummy@gmail.com
            01: {
            name:jay
            age:16
            }
    }
  }
}
```

and my "getafdData() function" path directory to "'info/'+ getuser".

the above updates work only if the "getuser" is the owner of the file or the node that holds the data, however i want it to be read by other authenticated users as well which i can't understand with $uid.

I have already Authenticate the login using "signInWithEmailAndPassword()" function by firebase

this is the code i use to authenticate

```
 try {
      var r = await this.fAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        "dummy@gmail.com",
        "123456"
      );
      if (r) {
        console.log("Successfully logged in!");
        await this.getafdData(); \\\ get the data when login

      }

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
```

```
async getafdData(){

var firebaseRef = this.afd.database.ref();
let data = await new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
   return firebaseRef.child('info/')
      .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
         console.log(snapshot.val());
         //resolve(data);


       }, function(err) {
         console.log(err);
         reject(err);
       })
    }); 
return data;
}
```

Can you advise what i am doing wrong? or rather correct steps i should do in order to access the $uid node?

Comment: What does `getafdData` do? It's probably best if you edit your question to include the code for that method. And what problem do you have? Is there an error message?

Comment: thanks btw for catching my mistake, i already have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `".read": true` rule allow any user to read data from `/info/$uid` **if they know the UID of the user whose data they want to read**. In your code you are however attaching a listener to `/info` and **nobody** has read permission on that node, so the read is rejected.

If you want everyone to be able to read all users nodes in one go, you should move the `".read": true,` rule to the `/info` level of your rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "info": {     
      ".read": true,
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
    }     
  }
}
```

Actually, since you say that you want to allow reading the user info by other *authenticated users*, that should probably be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "info": {     
      ".read": "auth != null",
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
    }     
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Frank, was following most of your answers on others question related to firebase. You hit the answer i want for this. I have another question, Is it necessary to add the User UID on the database node? in order to validate the statement $uid === $auth.uid?

Comment: And **IF** it is necessary, therefore i cannot flatten my node right? The thing is, below the User UID is also a uniqueid. flattening it, would make **the** other node without a User UID on top of it, which i cannot validate the statement $uid === auth.uid on write status